# how to remove brackets from an inserted tuple in a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples, brackets

please can somebody help me remove the extra brackets from my tuple list?

```
latest_Value = {"17:00:00": 100.00}

Dict1 = {"current value": 100, "stock_purchased": "false", "Historic value": [('16:00:00', 55.50), ("15:00:00", 45.50), ("14:00:00", 75.50),("13:00:00", 65.50), ("12:00:00", 55.50)]}

# converting the latest_value into a tuple
List_it = [(k, v) for k, v in latest_Value.items()]

# insert the tuple into the tuple list
Dict1['Historic value'].insert(0, List_it)

data2 = Dict1["Historic value"]
print(data2)

#output 

[[('17:00:00', 100.0)], ('16:00:00', 55.5), ('15:00:00', 45.5), ('14:00:00', 75.5), ('13:00:00', 65.5), ('12:00:00', 55.5)]
```

when the list is ammended, it adds a nested list instead of just the tuple.
How do you avoid this?

Kind Regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# converting the latest_value into a tuple
List_it = [(k, v) for k, v in latest_Value.items()]
```

That is, in fact, wrong. This converts the entire dict to tuples, not just the last key-value pair so `Dict1['Historic value'].insert(0, List_it)` adds the entire list of tuples to `Dict1['Historic value']`.

The fact that `latest_Value` contains a single key-value pair does not change the fact that `List_it` will be a list of tuples.

If you change to `Dict1['Historic value'].insert(0, List_it[0])` then you will get the output you want.